# Xcode preprocessor macro to check if Base SDK >= iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Is there any preprocessor macro to compile certain parts of code only if the Base SDK is 7.0 or higher? The "__IPHONE_7_0" defined constant seems to be linked to the iOS development target (and not to the base SDK).

I am using XCode 5 with iOS 7 and iOS 6.1 installed.

The reason why I am asking this is that I am currently transitioning an app from iOS 6 to iOS 7. There are quite a few things to adjust, and I would currently still like to compile my app with the iOS 6.1 as base SDK (and with development target iOS 6.0), but would already like to add some code that I will want for whenever I compile with iOS 7 SDK, but which does not compile if base SDK is iOS 6.1.

Example:

```
if ([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [_tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

This above piece of code does not compile with iOS 6.1 base SDK, as it complains about setSeparatorInset not being defined for UITableView. Hence I would like to include this piece of code inside a preprocessor directive, conditionally on the base SDK.

Comment: Why are you still compiling you app with the iOS 6 SDK when you are migrating to the iOS 7 SDK?

Comment: Because there are quite a few issues that I need to sort out which I have not finished yet (some UI artifacts that look weird with the new iOS7 SDK) but I need to compile a quick version now to sort out an urgent bug.

Answer (score 45):

You should read Apple's [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) where all those techniques are explained.

In particular, they recommend to use the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` macro to test against the **Deployment Target** of your project (minimum supported version), and for your case **use the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` macro to test the Base SDK used for compilation**.

---

*Example:*

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
// Only COMPILE this if compiled against BaseSDK iOS7.0 or greater
if ([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
   // Even when compiled with BaseSDK 7, only EXECUTE that if the user uses an
   // OS that support this method (namely if the user is running iOS7 or later,
   // but not for users running iOS6).
   [_tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
#endif
```

*Important note: You should use numeric constants in your comparison as if you test `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < __IPHONE_7_0` for example it won't work when using SDK 6, as `__IPHONE_7_0` is not defined thus evaluated to 0 in that context and your condition won't work as expected.*

Comment: Thanks, thought that would work, but still, if development target is iOS 6, then I get __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED = 60100 (even if Base SDK is iOS 7). I would need to set development target to iOS 7 for the condition to work.

Comment: I always use `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` since a while now, even for public projects deployed on GitHub and used by a lot of people — some still using Xcode4/SDK6, some using Xcode5/SDK7, all with various Deployment Target configurations — and in all my experience, `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` is always `70000` when building with  Xcode5/SDK7, contrary to `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` which depends on Deployment Target. Of course in any case I always use "Latest SDK" in the Build settings (you should never change that), but just change the Xcode version used.

Comment: In addition, did you read the documentation pointed to my link? They explain in which case you should use `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` and in which case you don't need to and what other correct techniques to use to achieve this kind of stuff.

Comment: I have read the link provided and I am indeed myself very surprised to have __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED returning __IPHONE_6_1 with the following set-up: XCode 5 with iOS SDK 7 and iOS SDK 6.1 installed, development target iOS 6.0 and base SDK iOS 7.

Comment: You installed SDK6 inside your Xcode5?! (probably by copying the directory in the Xcode.app bundle from your old Xcode4 to your new Xcode5 I suppose?) This May be the source of this strange behavior then. I suggest you keep an Xcode4.app if you need to build with SDK6 and have and Xcode5.app when you need to compile with SDK7 (and  remove the SDK6 you copied in Xcode5). This is what I do (I have Xcode4.app and Xcode5.app on my development Mac here) and not issue with `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED`.

Comment: Yes I do have XCode 5 and manually added the iOS 6.1 SDK. I shall probably need to try with XCode 4 installed aside. Still I am not 100% convinced that I will be able to have what I want (being able to mark a piece of code as not to be compiled depending on SDK version)

Comment: @AliSoftware Wow, I had the same problem: when I removed the 6.1 SDK from the Xcode package, everything worked properly.

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can use the `__IPHONE_7_0` define:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
    if ([_tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [_tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Had already tried that, but if development target is iOS 6.1 (but base SDK is iOS 7) then __IPHONE_7_0 is not defined, so it does not suit my purpose.

Comment: Yes and that is correct, thus when `__IPHONE_7_0 ` is not defined the code is between the `#ifdef` and `#endif` is not compiled. If you compile the same code with the iOS 7 SDK the code is included.

Comment: That is not the case. If I set the base SDK to iOS 7, the piece of code does not get compiled (for it to get compiled, I also need to set the development target to iOS 7, which is not what I want). I am looking for a preprocessor condition which compiles code if the base SDK is iOS 7 or higher, regardless of the value of the development target (which in fact I would like to keep at iOS 6)

Comment: Weird, I'm doing the same thing and for me it is working. Although I'm using Xcode 4.6 when doing any compiling for the iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't always hold true. Right now the SDK in XCode 7.3.1 is for iOS 9 but the headers have a #define for __IPHONE_10_0.

Answer (score 13):

As per Apple Doc you should use `NSFoundationVersionNumber` to distinguish between iOS 7 and others. You can make it simpler using following macros:

```
#define isIOS6 floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 
#define isIOS7 floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1
```

and then later in code do

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
    if (isIOS7) {
       // Do additional stuff for iOS 7.
    } 
#endif
```

Yes you should check on both compile-time (with `#ifdef`) and run-time (with `isIOS7`) this way you will be able to compile with iOS6 SDK , iOS7 SDK, and also iOS7 SDK with an iOS6 target.

OH! Remember that you cannot do `if (!isIOS7)` you have to use `if (isIOS6)`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/

Comment: If by isIOS6 you mean 6.1 or earlier, it should be <=.

Comment: @Jano Thank you for noticing that. I've fixed both definitions.

Comment: Can you avoid using floor for the greater than comparison, then compare >= with 7. That way you don't need to rely on the fact that 7 follows 6.1 with nothing in between

Comment: @graveley You cannot do that because in iOS6 SDK you don't have NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7 definition.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use this macro

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:(v) options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

e.g `if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.1")) {[self doSomething];} else {[self doSomethingElse];}`

Comment: This is good runtime check, but the question is about compile-time SDK version.

Comment: Don't check the system version,  but check the SDK version like: `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) `for iOS 6 or lower.  Just as Apple mentions in there [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't test for the sdk but for availability of the method / class IMHO. So not with a precompiled at all

Comment: But sometime, especially in libraries, you want to be able to detect the SDK to include some features or new methods. which you can always do with the detection of a method or class.

Comment: "which you can" or "which you can't" ? can you tell me about such a feature?

Comment: MIND: I do use the macros mentioned here and I totally get that there is an exception to every 'rule' -- which is why I didn't down vote you :D (just teasing!)

Comment: Sometimes you have to test for SDK on preprocessor level, because new methods won’t even compile, when called from older SDK.

Comment: ok you have to check for declarations. ok ... not for the calling mentioned here but ok :)