# Check Base SDK at run time

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm building a library and some of the functionality is broken when the app using it is running newer base SDK (xCode 6, Base SDK iOS 8.0).

When trying to fix the issue, the Applications built with older SDKs are broken. (xCode 5, Base SDK 7.1)

It's not related to the version on the device.

Is there a way to check in code what's the Base SDK set by the App?

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros. As described by rckoenes in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789958/xcode-preprocessor-macro-to-check-if-base-sdk-ios-7-0) you can use macro `__IPHONE_7_0` to know that you are compiling with iOS 7.0 SDK. For iOS 8.0 SDK you can use `__IPHONE_8_0` macro of course. These macros are defined in `Availability.h` header.

Also be sure to read [Apple's SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) to understand more about working with multiple SDK's.

Comment: The problem is that I'm creating a library. and these flags are set when I build it, and not affected by the app using the library. if I build the library with Base SDK 8.0, it will enter the #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0 even if the app is built With Base SDK 7.1.

Comment: SDK 7.1 does not have __IPHONE_8_0 macro defined. Are you sure you do not mean just it will enter this on iOS 7.1 device, but built with SDK 8.0?

Comment: No, the library is built for 8.0 (with the macros in code), app is built for 7.1. when running on 8.0 device, I want the library to 'enter' the 7.1 code, because the app is built for it. but it enters the 8.0 code instead.

Comment: It makes sense that it enters that code, because this is a macro, which is resolved at compile time and if you will compile library with 8.0 SDK, it will always enter that code. You must modify the library then, but what you are saying does not make sense. Are you saying you are building library with 8.0 SDK and then you build the entire app with 7.1 SDK? Wouldn't that cause linker errors?

Comment: No linker errors. I don't want to have 2 versions of my library, one for apps that are building for 7.1 and one for 8.0. that's why I'm trying to find a way knowing which sdk the apps are targeting.

Comment: In this case, you will need to rebuild your library for 7.1.

Comment: But then it's built on 7.1 and won't run the 8.0 code

Comment: You won't be able to run 8.0 code on an app build with 7.1 SDK anyway.

Comment: yes you can, upgrade your device to iOS 8.0, all the installed apps are built for 7.1..

Comment: Which installed apps do you mean?