# Xcode 8 XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR macro - Compilation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have an iOS Project which is not compiling in XCode 8. if i fix the compilation issue, it is not working in XCode 7.
But i need to make the project working in both XCode 7 and 8. so i am trying to use the preprocessor macro to do the conditional compilation

i have defined the macro in the Xcode Preprocessor Macros section like below

> ```
> XCODE_VERS=$(XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR)
> ```

My code checks the version like below

```
#if XCODE_VERS == "0700"
@interface SampleTableCell : UITableViewCell
#else
@interface SampleTableCell : UITableViewCell<CAAnimationDelegate>
#endif
```

In Xcode 8, XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR is translated in to 0800. This is not valid octal number.
It works fine in Xcode 7, but in XCode 8, i am getting the following compilation error

[image: Compilation Error]

Is there any work around to use the XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR macro is Xcode 8.

Comment: It seems as if you want to check which SDK you are compiling against. Have you looked into using the already available preprocessor macros for that? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789958/

Comment: Thanks, instead of Xcode version, as you suggested i can use iOS Base SDK (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) to avoid the compilation issue. but XCODE version related build variables can not be used from Xcode 8 onwards. I have submitted a bug report to apple. Can you respond your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation issue is resolved by using **__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED** macro instead of **XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR** build attribute.

Now the project is usable in both Xcode 7 and Xcode 8.

Since the **XCODER_VERSION_MAJOR** and few more attributes which stores the XCODE version holding the invalid octal number, so these attributes will become unusable from Xcode 8. bug has created for the same.